# Variable Causing my page to crash

Tags: php, html, css

So i've been working on a way of getting the URL and using the number of '/' to work out where to sent to user when on the site.

I have spent a while trying to debug it and have fixed it with something that i dont believe should be effecting it at all.

Could someone look at my code and let me know why it's doing this.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlcount = 0;
$strcount = 0;
$strlen = strlen($url);
while ($strlen > $strcount){
    //echo "len: " . $strlen . ' | ';
    //echo "count: " . $strcount . ' | ';
    //echo "letter: " . substr($url, $strcount, 1) . '<br>';
    if (substr($url, $strcount, 1)=="/"){
        $urlcount++;
    }
    $strcount++;
}
//Edit: (I Added the variable to reset the strcount here)
```

So This code above seems to be causing the problem. The problem btw is that when loading the page the browser will not run any of the CSS or JS files in the site. Just removing this code will allow it to run normally.

What i did to fix this is reset the $strcount back to 0 and then it will run.
I dont understand why that is happening or why setting strcount to 0 will get it to work again.

I have tried different values for strcount, the url is 43 chars long, i've set it to 50, 1, 43 in a way to get it to work as possibily the input is bad but only 0 works.

The page it self is to check if the user is logged in.

Below is all the code in my page so you can get context:

```
<?php
require "dbcon.php";
//Check Perms
//Errors

//Clean Up Old Sessions from DB
$session_clear=mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM global_sessions WHERE expiration < NOW()");
if (!$session_clear) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

$key = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_COOKIE['session']);    

//Gets Login information Regarding the data inputed
$results=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT u.student_id, u.school_id, u.username, u.nickname, u.email, u.house, u.verified, u.permission_group FROM global_sessions s LEFT JOIN global_userdata u ON s.user_id = u.student_id WHERE s.hash = '$key'");
if (!$results) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

//Gets URL and counts '/' to work out where is is in the directory listing
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$urlcount = 0;
$strcount = 0;
$strlen = strlen($url);
while ($strlen > $strcount){
    //echo "len: " . $strlen . ' | ';
    //echo "count: " . $strcount . ' | ';
    //echo "letter: " . substr($url, $strcount, 1) . '<br>';
    if (substr($url, $strcount, 1)=="/"){
        $urlcount++;
    }
    $strcount++;
}
$strcount = 0;
//Check School is set, if nots logs the user out and returns to index
$school = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_COOKIE['school']);
if (empty($school)){
    if ($urlcount == 3){
        setcookie("session", $key, time()-3600, '/');
        header("location: loggedout/index.php?login_error=notschool");
        exit;
    }elseif ($urlcount == 4){
        setcookie("session", $key, time()-3600, '/');
        header("location: ../loggedout/index.php?login_error=notschool");
        exit;
    }else{
        die("Error: An Error Occurred - (Make Log) [L1]");
    }
}
//Gets School Information From Database 
$results2=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from global_schools WHERE code = '" . $school . "'");
if (!$results2) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

//Checks if logged in.

$count = mysqli_num_rows($results);
if ($count == 0) {
    //No Account Found - And Redirect
    if ($urlcount == 3){
        header("location: loggedout/index.php?login_error=invalid");
        exit;
    }elseif ($urlcount == 4){
        header("location: ../loggedout/index.php?login_error=invalid");
        exit;
    }else{
        die("Error: An Error Occurred - (Make Log) [L2]");
    }
} elseif ($count > 1) {
    //More than one account with the same unique details
    die('Error: Aaaah too many people!!! I get scared when there are crowds. Please contact an admin and tell them that there is a problem!');
    exit;
} else {
    //Login Successful
    //Get user Details and store them in a global Variable
    $logged_user_details = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
    //Get school Details and store them in a global Variable
    $logged_school_details = mysqli_fetch_array($results2);
    //Store Details in web page in commented form
    echo "<!-- ";
    print_r ($logged_user_details);
    print_r ($logged_school_details);
    echo "-->";
    //Check if account if verified
    if ($logged_user_details['verified'] != 1){
        die("You haven't verified your account. Please check your emails and click the link to complete your registration. Then click back on your browser!");
}
    //Check if the user has the same school linked with their account as they are trying to login on - Redirect if not
     if ($logged_school_details['school_id'] != $logged_user_details['school_id']){
         if ($urlcount == 3){
             setcookie("session", $key, time()-3600, '/');
             setcookie("school", $school, time()-3600, '/');
             header('Location: ' . $school . '/notschool');
             exit;
        }elseif ($urlcount == 4){
             setcookie("session", $key, time()-3600, '/');
             setcookie("school", $school, time()-3600, '/');
             header('Location: ../' . $school . '/notschool');
             exit;
        }else{
             die("Error: An Error Occurred - (Make Log) [L3]");
        }
    }
}

//!! Check if the user has accepted the terms and conditions !! - Might need a rewrite
/*$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT agreed FROM users WHERE id='".$logged_user_details['id']."'");
 if (!$result) {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
#header('Location: ../index.php');
$agreedresult=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
//echo $agreedresult['agreed'];
if ($agreedresult['agreed'] == 0){
    setcookie("session", $key, time()+1200, '/');
    setcookie("id", $logged_user_details['id'], time()+60, '/');
    header('Location: ../tsandcs.php');
    exit;
}*/

//Login successful, Set login information - Session Key
$result=mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE global_sessions SET expiration=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) WHERE hash='$key'");
if (!$result) {
die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
setcookie("session", $key, time()+1200, '/');
?>
```

Comment: It is strange that resetting the string strcount should do anything. You should check your logs to see what is going on.

A suggestion, instead of counting / in the URL you could use explode, http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php. It will return an array by splitting a string by a given character. 

$request_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look into explode.

And yeah, i've been coding for long enough now too be really confused why i need to reset a variable. I fear it's something later in the code crashing on the variable when calling it, but I dont call it anywhere from what find says!